# Slow response from Docker container inside Kubernetes pod

Tags: python, docker, grpc

I have deployed a Docker container which is of grpc2 streaming bidirectional application inside a Kubernetes pod. When the pod is up the application runs fine, but the response from the application is slow. If I run the application manually inside the pod, the response is pretty good.

Is there any problem starting an application using Docker inside the Kubernetes pod?

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import psutil
import os
#q = ""
#for i in cpul:
#    q+=str(i)+","
#q= q[:-1]    
#os.system("taskset -p -c %s %d" % (q, os.getpid()))
import argparse
import collections
import queue as Queue
import grpc
import webrtcvad
from proto import stt_pb2
from proto import stt_pb2_grpc
from pytz import timezone
import datetime
import os
import threading
import time
import uuid
import wave
import requests
from itertools import cycle
from concurrent import futures
import stream
import subprocess
import json
from logger import get_logger
import sys
import multiprocessing
logger = get_logger(__name__)

class IterableQueue():
        def __init__(self, Q):
                self.Q = Q
                self.predicate = True

        def __iter__(self):
                return self

        def _check(self, x):
                if x['is_final'] == True:
                        self.predicate = False

        def __next__(self):
                if self.predicate:
                        item = self.Q.get()
                        self._check(item)
                        return item
                else:
                        raise StopIteration

class Listener(stt_pb2_grpc.ListenerServicer):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frames = {}
        self.lang={}
        self.emailid = {}
        self.response_time = {}
        self.vendorname = {}
        self.timestamp = {}
        self.userid = {}
        logger.info("Server ON")

    def UpdateDB(self,key,frames,transcript,confidence,email="default@b.c"):
       // Updating data to database

    def _splitStream(self, request_iterator, listQueues, key):
        // logic to split stream

    def _mergeStream(self, asr_response_iterator, responseQueue, asr, key):
        for asr_response in asr_response_iterator:
           // merge stream code
            responseQueue.put(toClient_json)

    def DoAToB(self, request_iterator, context):
        print("Serving request using "+str(os.getpid()))
        logger.info("Serving request using "+str(os.getpid()))
        // logic to do decoding


def serve(port,i):
    server = grpc.server()
    ps = psutil.Process()
    os.system("taskset -p -c %d %d" % (i, os.getpid()))
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:%d' % port)
    print("Server starting in port "+str(port)+" with cpu "+ str(i))
    server.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(60 * 60 * 24)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ps = psutil.Process()
    cpul=ps.cpu_affinity() # CPU affinity list for the process

    no_cpu=os.environ["cpu_server"] # Number of CPUs from pod spec
    #num_cpus = len(cpul)

    first_port = 9000
    ports = []
    for i in range(int(no_cpu)):
        portnum = first_port + i
        ports.append(str(portnum))
    port_pool = cycle(ports)

    #print("No of Cpu's: "+no_cpu)

    if ( len(cpul) == int(no_cpu) ):
        # Exclusiveness in set. Bind to cpu list
        for i in cpul:
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=serve,args=(int(next(port_pool)),i))
            p.start()
    else:
        # No exclusiveness. Bind to first "no_cpu" cpus.
        for i in range(0,int(no_cpu)):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=serve,args=(int(next(port_pool)),i))
            p.start()
```

We are starting grpc bidirectional application manually to get the pretty good response. Log details of results:

Actual:

```
last chuck of bidirectional stream time taken: 1.287374
```

Expected:

```
last chuck of bidirectional stream time taken: 0.068374
```

Comment: When it runs with problem when started manually, then it might be the way you start it that causes the problem.

Comment: What in your code produces that timing message?  Your question leads off with a question about launching other processes; where is that in the code?